# Views right and bottom of layout behave differently than views on left and top when moving

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I'm creating a game app, and when I want to create intro page, I have 4 bitmaps that should "enter" the scene, one on each side (top, left, right, bottom). They are all programmatically added to scene.

Scene have simple layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/playground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        >
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have determining playgroud view size (in pixels) and adding 4 images. Left should be added at the left side of view and then moved to original position. Same for all other images, they are outside of view, and the moved inside a view.

Sample of adding left image:

```
RelativeView playground = view.findViewById(R.id.playground);

/* some playground size calculations..., after ViewTreeObserver */
int playAreaWidth = playground.getWidth();
int playAreaHeight = playground.getHeight();

ImageView leftBack = new ImageView(requireContext());
leftBack.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
leftBack.setImageResource(R.drawable.back_left);
playground.addView(leftBack);

/* some image size calculations... gettnig variables maxLeftWidth */
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(maxLeftWidth, playAreaHeight);
params.leftMargin = -maxLeftWidth;
params.topMargin = 0;
leftBack.setLayoutParams(params);
```

and a simple animation, to move left image from outside a view to x coordinate 0

```
Animation a = new Animation() {
    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsMoving = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(maxLeftWidth, playAreaHeight);
        paramsMoving.leftMargin = (int) (-maxLeftWidth + maxLeftWidth * interpolatedTime);
        paramsMoving.topMargin = 0;
        leftBack.setLayoutParams(paramsMoving);
    }
};
a.setDuration(300);
leftBack.startAnimation(a);
```

and that works as expected. Same for top image moving down.

However, **problem is with bottom and right images**. Instead of moving from outside a view into a view, they just scale. Looks like right edge of a right image and bottom edge of a bottom image cannot be outside a view. `x` position of right image and `y` position of bottom image are changing correctly during animation, but images have not proper width (right image) and height (bottom image).

Is there any way to force it to be displayed in a proper size outside a view?

Comment: Different Solution but why not choose [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout) with `ConstraintSet` for animation, or even better, [`MotionLayout`](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout) ([Examples](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout/examples)),  specifically made for animations.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about `ConstraintLayout` or `MotionLayout` (like [Lalit Fauzdar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8244632/lalit-fauzdar) said) but, I'm still not familiar with them and there will be a lot of static  animation views, all dynamically added, depending how game goes on.

Solution I found is just to use `FrameLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` (and `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` instead of `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`) and all works like a charm.

[image]